# XML - how to use namespace prefixes

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have this XML at http://localhost/file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<val:Root xmlns:val="http://www.hw-group.com/XMLSchema/ste/values.xsd">
<Agent>
<Version>2.0.3</Version>
<XmlVer>1.01</XmlVer>
<DeviceName>HWg-STE</DeviceName>
<Model>33</Model>
<vendor_id>0</vendor_id>
<MAC>00:0A:DA:01:DA:DA</MAC>
<IP>192.168.1.1</IP>
<MASK>255.255.255.0</MASK>
<sys_name>HWg-STE</sys_name>
<sys_location/>
<sys_contact>
HWg-STE:For more information try http://www.hw-group.com
</sys_contact>
</Agent>
<SenSet>
<Entry>
<ID>215</ID>
<Name>Home</Name>
<Units>C</Units>
<Value>27.7</Value>
<Min>10.0</Min>
<Max>40.0</Max>
<Hyst>0.0</Hyst>
<EmailSMS>1</EmailSMS>
<State>1</State>
</Entry>
</SenSet>
</val:Root>
```

I am trying to read this from my c# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("http://localhost/file.xml");
            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            // Create an XmlNamespaceManager to resolve the default namespace.
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("val", "http://www.hw-group.com/XMLSchema/ste/values.xsd");

            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/val:SenSet/val:Entry"); 
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                string name = node["Name"].InnerText;
                string value = node["Value"].InnerText;

            Console.Write("name\t{0}\value\t{1}", name, value);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Problem is that the node is empty. I understand this is a common newbie problem when reading XML, still not able to solve what I am doing wrong, probably something with the Namespace "val" ?

Comment: I've updated title. when asking questions please try make title reflect the problem. In your case you seem to already figured out that loading of XML worked, but it still in the title. Note: don't forget to vote on answers and accept one you find most useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the namespace manager into the SelectNodes() 
method.

Edit: corrected code

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/val:Root/SenSet/Entry", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Made it work with XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/val:Root/SenSet/Entry", nsmgr);

Answer (score 0):

Just change you Xpath to:

```
XmlNodeList nodes1 = root.SelectNodes("/val:Root/SenSet/Entry",nsmgr);
```

Or:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("SenSet/Entry");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath query string should be:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/val:Root/SenSet/Entry", nsmgr);
```

or more concisely,

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//SenSet/Entry", nsmgr);
```